# Openstack instance is not getting its public IP

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I have openstack up and running along with the public network. I am able to attach floating IPs and external gateway to routers. Everything seems to be working just fine apart from when launching an instance with fixed public IP.

When launching an instance this specific part of the log grabbed my attention:

checking http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/instance-id
failed 1/20: up 182.35. request failed
failed 2/20: up 184.36. request failed
failed 3/20: up 186.36. request failed
failed 4/20: up 188.37. request failed
failed 5/20: up 190.37. request failed
failed 6/20: up 192.38. request failed
failed 7/20: up 194.38. request failed
failed 8/20: up 196.39. request failed
failed 9/20: up 198.40. request failed
failed 10/20: up 200.40. request failed
failed 11/20: up 202.41. request failed
failed 12/20: up 204.41. request failed
failed 13/20: up 206.42. request failed
failed 14/20: up 208.42. request failed
failed 15/20: up 210.43. request failed
failed 16/20: up 212.43. request failed
failed 17/20: up 214.44. request failed
failed 18/20: up 216.45. request failed
failed 19/20: up 218.45. request failed
failed 20/20: up 220.46. request failed
failed to read iid from metadata. tried 20
failed to get instance-id of datasource
Top of dropbear init script
Starting dropbear sshd: failed to get instance-id of datasource

I tried to solve this issue by launching the instance with config drive parameter but still not working. If anyone has an idea on how to solve this problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: Does it work if you create a port in the external network first, then use the port-id to create an instance? You don't specify versions, it might be an issue with cloud-init which fails to query other datasources than meta-data.

Comment: I tried that but it is not working. The version of cirros is 0.6.2. However I have tried with my ubuntu 22.04 image which works in my other environment but here still not reaching 169.254.169.254#

Comment: Then you need to check if your metadata-agent is working and what it logs.